# thread safe queue with interrupt function

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

I try to implement a thread safe queue with the interrupt function (interrupt all threads who are blocking to take data from queue).

```
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

/**
 * throw the exception when waiting is interrupted by other threads.
 */
class BlockInterrupt
{
public:
    BlockInterrupt()
    {
    }

};

/**
 * RAII, execute the function in destructor.
 */
class Final
{
public:
    explicit Final(const std::function<void()>& final)
       :m_final(final)
    {
    }

    ~Final()
    {
        try
        {
            m_final();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
        }
    }

private:
    const std::function<void()> m_final;

};

template<typename T>
class BlockQueue
{
public:
    BlockQueue()
    {
    }

    /**
     * queue will be destroyed, interrupt all blocking thread.
     * the mutex will be locked until the deconstruction is finished.
     */
    ~BlockQueue()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if(m_waiter_count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        m_interrupted = true;
        //wake up all block threads.
        m_wait_finished.notify_all();
        //wait for all threads are interrupted.
        m_interrupt_finished.wait(lock, [this](){return m_waiter_count == 0;});
    }

    BlockQueue(const BlockQueue&) = delete;
    BlockQueue(BlockQueue&&) = delete;
    BlockQueue& operator=(const BlockQueue&) = delete;
    BlockQueue& operator=(BlockQueue&&) = delete;

    BlockQueue& push(const T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.push(value);
        //if some threads is wait for taking, notify one.
        if(m_waiter_count > 0)
        {
            m_wait_finished.notify_one();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    BlockQueue& push(T&& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.push(std::move(value));
        //if some threads is wait for taking, notify one.
        if(m_waiter_count > 0)
        {
            m_wait_finished.notify_one();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    BlockQueue& emplace(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        //if some threads is wait for taking, notify one.
        if(m_waiter_count > 0)
        {
            m_wait_finished.notify_one();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    T take()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if(!m_queue.empty())
        {
            T value = std::move(const_cast<T&>(m_queue.front()));
            m_queue.pop();
            return value;
        }
        if(m_interrupted)
        {
            throw BlockInterrupt();
        }
        //if the count of waiter is overflow.
        if(m_waiter_count == std::numeric_limits<decltype(m_waiter_count)>::max())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("The counter for waiter of block queue is overflow.");
        }
        //the call must be blocked.
        ++m_waiter_count;
        Final final([this]()
        {
            //this code will be execute anyhow.
            --m_waiter_count;
            if(m_waiter_count == 0 && m_interrupted == true)
            {
                //if count of waiter is zero, and some threads call the interrupt(), notify all.
                m_interrupt_finished.notify_all();
            }
        });
        m_wait_finished.wait(lock, [this](){return !m_queue.empty() || m_interrupted;});
        if(m_interrupted)
        {
            throw BlockInterrupt();
        }
        T value = std::move(const_cast<T&>(m_queue.front()));
        m_queue.pop();
        return value;
    }

    bool try_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if(!m_queue.empty())
        {
            value = std::move(const_cast<T&>(m_queue.front()));
            m_queue.pop();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * interrupt all block threads, return until all threads are interrupted.
     */
    BlockQueue& interrupt() noexcept
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if(m_waiter_count == 0)
        {
            //no waiter, return.
            m_interrupted = false;
            return *this;
        }

        m_interrupted = true;
        //wake up all block threads.
        m_wait_finished.notify_all();
        //wait for all threads are interrupted.
        m_interrupt_finished.wait(lock, [this](){return m_waiter_count == 0;});
        m_interrupted = false;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    /**
     * mutex for accessing of "m_queue", "m_interrupted", "m_waiter_count".
     */
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::queue<T> m_queue;
    /**
     * express whether the queue is interrupted.
     */
    bool m_interrupted = false;
    /**
     * count of threads blocked.
     */
    std::uint32_t m_waiter_count = 0;
    /**
     * condition variable for notifying that the queue is readable or interrupted (so the threads blocked should be awakened).
     */
    std::condition_variable m_wait_finished;
    /**
     * condition variable for notifying that no thread is blocking (so interrupt has finished).
     */
    std::condition_variable m_interrupt_finished;

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    BlockQueue<int> q;

    std::thread taker1([&]()
    {
        try
        {
            q.take();
        }
        catch(const BlockInterrupt&)
        {
            std::cout << "taker1 interrupted." << std::endl;
        }
    });

    std::thread taker2([&]()
    {
        try
        {
            q.take();
        }
        catch(const BlockInterrupt&)
        {
            std::cout << "taker2 interrupted." << std::endl;
        }
    });

    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.5s);

    std::thread interrupter([&]()
    {
        q.interrupt();
    });

    taker1.join();
    taker2.join();
    interrupter.join();

    return 0;
}
```

thanks for review.